# Element Colors: Fast Loading in Web

Tags: html, angular, reactjs

I am designing a highly interactive and responsive website. I am trying to keep the design elements as minimalistic as possible.

Is there any take on if any particular color will be rendered faster in the web browser?

Comment: Nothing like that every element is loaded with same speed when applying CSS styles, if it does not wait for any data from server

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your reply.